# Change Text color on tap in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui, textview

I have defined a `List` of `Text` inside SwiftUI in the following way.

```
struct SampleView: View {
    private let list: [String] = ["Tapping each line should change its color from grey to black", "First Line", "Second Line", "Third Line."]
    
    var body: some View {
        ScrollViewReader { value in
            List {
                ForEach(Array(zip(list, list.indices)), id: \.0) { eachString, index in
                    Text(eachString)
                        .bold().font(.largeTitle)
                        .foregroundColor(.gray)
                        .onTapGesture {
                            self.foregroundColor(.black)
                        }
                }
            }.listStyle(.plain)
        }.frame(maxHeight: .infinity)
    }
}

struct SampleView_Preview: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        SampleView()
    }
}
```

I need to be able to change the `foregroundColor` of a particular TextView whenever the user taps on it.

`CustomString` is a class that I defined that conforms to `Hashable`. I can't get it to conform to `ObservableObject` at the same time which means I can't change its value inside the `onTapGesture` block.

I also can't remove the `index` from the loop as I'll need that too.

TIA.

Comment: Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to improve, edit and format your questions. 

Without a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) it is impossible to help you troubleshoot.

Answer (score -1):

Don't take it personal at all, just keep in mind that Stackoverflow is a great way to share between developers, but all the basics are much more clear in the documentation and samples from Apple. They are incredibly well done by the way.

https://developer.apple.com/tutorials/swiftui

And for your problem, you must declare a state variable with your color, so when the color changes, the view is regenerated.

I have not tested your code, because you don't provide a copy/paste ready to run playground or view class, but you see the principle.

One sure thing is that if you need each text cell to update independently, you should make a "TextCell" subview or whatever, that has it's own color. Not at the highest level. In your code, I presume all cells will get the same color, since it is defined at top level of your List.

Happy new year :)

```
...
@State var color: Color = .gray

var myString: [CustomString]
...

ScrollViewReader { value in
    List {
        ForEach(Array(zip(myString, myString.indices)), id: \.0) { eachString, index in
        Text(eachString.text)
        .foregroundColor(color)
        .onTapGesture {
            self.color = .black
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your input. I have updated my question to make it minimally reproducable. I have also tried out your solution which unfortunately has not worked. Creating an `@State` variable changes the color of every other `TextView` before that. All these `Text` are actually created inside a `ForEach` loop.

Comment: That was anticipated in my answer. I wrote that you need to move the @State in a custom view of your own containing the text, and use it in the loop.